# How to pass parameters to a deep react-navigation Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I have a react-native app using react-navigation. I want to pass some props all along the stack navigator, but not sure what is the right thing to do.

To give more details, my screens are:

- ListThingsScreen: List all things.
- ShowThingScreen: Show details of the thing.
- EditThingScreen: Edit the thing.

They are organized in such way:

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ListThings: ListThingsScreen,
    ShowThing: ShowThingScreen,
    EditThing: EditThingScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "ListThings"
  }
);

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack
});
```

An app user:

1. Log in.
2. See all things (in ListThingsScreen).
3. Click on one of them, jump to ShowThingScreen to see its details.
4. Click on a button of the details screen, jump to EditThingScreen to edit the thing.
5. Once finished editing, jump back to ShowThingScreen.

In ListThingsScreen `componentDidMount()`, I will make async call to fetch logged in user data such as `userId`, `username`, etc. I want all screens in the stack knows about them to behave correctly when show and when edit.

Solutions I can think of:

1. Pass parameters to routes, as suggested by react-navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html). This works, but as I have more screens in the stack, I write too much code like `navigation.push("RouteName", {user})` and `navigation.getParam("user", "No user")`.

This is pretty much the only solution I have found. An alternative is to use React context. I like this approach better, however I want to use react-navigation and the concept of `Router` and `Route` don't exist in the library.

```js
// ListItemsScreen.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

<UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
  <Router>
    <div className="app-container">
      <Route path="/show/:thingId" component={ShowThing} />
      <Route path="/edit/:thingId" component={EditThing} />
    </div>
  </Router>
</UserContext.Provider>

// ShowItemScreen.js
<UserContext.Consumer>
  {({user}) => (...)}
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

Which approach is more "correct"? If it is the 2nd approach, how can I do it with react-navigation?

Comment: Your solution is using a state container to store the entire state of your app, such as Redux. Read more here: https://redux.js.org

Comment: Yes, I can use Redux, but I don't plan to. I prefer solving this with React Context.

Comment: You could use the first solution and provide functions to pass parameters back. I'm not familiar with react context.